# Where in USA can I buy high end telescopic surf rods for fishing?

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

I am in USA and I am looking for "high end" ($100 or more) telescopic fishing rods for surf/beach fishing.

The specs I need are :

```
- 12 ft (or more), 
- Lure weight up to 8oz/250 grams (or more), 
- Extra Floating guides (if possible) 
- Action is "medium-heavy".
```

Online or physical shops in USA generally don't sell such rods. For Ex., Cabela's sells a low-end one for $20. Bass Pro shops does not sell any. Amazon USA sells some from Daiwa, but they are a bit short of my specs. Moreover, they cost about $200 & most of the cost is due to overseas shipping. Thus, in most cases you essentially get a 50-100$ rod for about $200. I'd like to spend more on a better quality rod & less on shipping.

I am looking for rods from brands like DAM (Germany), Daiwa (Japan), Tubertini (Italy) etc. but could not find any dealers which sell them in USA.

Are there any American or international dealers who can ship them to USA at "reasonable" prices ?

Comment: In my opinion this is not a price-shopping assistance question. It might be in a gray area around it, but I believe it has merit and is clearly different from the typical "what ... is the best for under 50$". This asks about any possible means to purchase a specific type of product in one area. Yes, a purchase channel might get outdated in the future, but could still help to find successors or similar options.

Comment: On further thought, retracting my close vote. I believe this would help anyone who wants to source a high end fishing rod.

Comment: @imsodin - thank you for starting the discussion and supporting me. Now, hopefully, my question won't be closed or down voted for mysterious reasons, which we often seen on stack overflow and such :)

Comment: I think your best bet is checking AMZ or eBay at this point. I know there are some AMZ brand managers(I'm pretty sure https://webycorp.com/ does a lot of outdoors stuff, so maybe they've got smth?)

Answer (score 2):

Not a very specific answer but I can share that I've noticed friends who are big on (fly) fishing purchasing direct-from-maker for high end or specialized equipment, whether domestically or internationally. They find an example of what they're looking for and reach out to the source to see where it came from and if one can be ordered, and go from there.

Have you been able to find any examples online of what you're looking for, better yet with any contact info whatsoever associated with it? That's probably the place to start from.

Comment: If you walk on a beach and find people fishing there (or about to start or just packing away) talk with them and get names/brands.

Comment: Cr0 - Thanks. I am waiting for replies to emails I had sent to some manufacturers. The shipping cost is the problem, which I now updated in my question. Shipping is usually about $100 or so and I would rather spend more on quality than on shipping.